# Push to Other Branch Git

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, push

I'm working on a rails app that I occasionally push to a staging server to test things out. I can easily push my local master to the remote master (I called it origin).  I'm running into a problem where I'm trying out 2 frameworks, each in their own branch on my local machine.  I'd like to see how the frameworks work on the remote server.

How can I push from local:Framework1 to remote:master (because the staging server has scripts that deploy master from the staging server's git repo)?

Comment: That would push my master branch to the remote server, no? I'm looking to push the branch `Framework1` to the remote's master

Comment: That should push your current branch to remote master.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev git push without :destination pushes to the matching ref.

Comment: This isn't really a RoR question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git push origin Framework1:refs/heads/master` should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Merge Framework1 into local master, then push origin master. You'll need to perform a clean merge locally before you start mucking up the remote server anyway.